# Bot Framework V3 Email Json object

Tags: c#, json, azure, botframework

I'm trying to make the bot reply to emails in Bot Framework V3. However i'm struggling to understand how to call the object from the dialog or even how to create the JSON object.
The examples have been deleted by microsoft so there's almost no examples or documentation on how to do this.
Does anyone have an example of a Dialog replying to an email that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

This is my current code but its not working:

Dialog:
Thank you for your reply.
This dialog would be enough? What about the recipients, etc?
The documentation is very scares and only tells you how does the Json have to look.

This is my code:

messagecontroller:

```
        else if (activity.ChannelId == "email")
        {

            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EmailDialogDante());
        }
```

Dialog:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var message = context.Activity as IMessageActivity;

        var reply = context.MakeMessage();

        reply.ChannelData = new BotchannelData();
        {
            ChannelData channelData = new ChannelData();

            ChannelDataInter channelDataInter = new ChannelDataInter();

        }


        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        // await fetchOrderDetails(context, query);
    }
```

and these are my Json Objects:

```
public class BotchannelData
{

  [JsonProperty("channelData")]
public ChannelData ChannelData
{
    get;
    internal set;
}
}
}


namespace SimpleEchoBot.EmailJson
{
public class ChannelData
{
    public ChannelData()
    {
        this.Type = "message";
        this.Locale = "en-Us";
        this.ChannelID = "email";

    }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("locale")]
    public dynamic Locale { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("channelID")]
    public dynamic ChannelID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("from")]
    public From From { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("recipient")]
    public Recipient Recipient { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("conversation")]
    public Conversation Conversation { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("channelData")]
    public ChannelDataInter ChannelDataInter { get; internal set; }

}
}

namespace SimpleEchoBot.EmailJson
{
public class ChannelDataInter
{
    public ChannelDataInter()
    {
        this.HTML = "test";
        this.Subject = "testing";
        this.Importance = "high";


    }
    [JsonProperty("html")]
    public string HTML { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public dynamic Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("importance")]
    public dynamic Importance { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Email channel specific properties can be set in **ChannelData** using something like:

```
if (message.ChannelId == ChannelIds.Email)
{
    var reply = message.CreateReply();
    reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        htmlBody = "<html><body style=\"font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;\">This is the email body!</body></html>",
        subject = "This is the email subject",
        importance = "high"
    });
    //send reply to user
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

Some references to pertinent documentation:

[Customize emails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#customize-emails)

[Create a custom Email message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-a-custom-email-message)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This dialog would be enough? What about the recipients, etc?
The documentation is very scares and only tells you how does the Json have to look.

Comment: the recipient will be the user that emailed the bot.

Comment: You should use the MessageReceived to send the reply instead of StartAsync.  If you use message.CreateReply(); then the From and Recipient fields will be set correctly already.

Comment: Thank you.
However 
    var message = context.Activity as IMessageActivity
Which comes from StartAsync(IdialogContext context)
Doesn't hae CreateReply() method. The only thing similar to that would be
    message.CreateOAuthReplyAsync
And that doesn't seem like the method I need.

Comment: ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply()